# Limit the number of SMS sent

Tags: python, sms, at-command

i developed a python script that send sms from the computer to send an sms to a set of phone numbers. The operation is as follows, one gives a phone number and the amount of number to generate from it, then the script does something similar to a "subnetting" and sends the sms, one by one, to the various numbers generated.

For example, if I give you generate 1000 from 973254509, then it would start sending from 973254000 to 973254999.

The problem is that if I put 10 it works, 100 works, but immediately if I put 1000 it stops working (AT commands keep returning ok and CMGS: number) but the sms doesn't arrive anymore.

Sometimes a utility that I have installed tells me that the SIM is full.

The tests were as follows:

1) Seed 973254509, quantity to be generated 10. .... The SMS was sent

2) Seed 973254509, quantity to generate 100. .... The SMS was sent

3) Seed 973254509, quantity to be generated 1000. .... The SMS was not sent

In theory it should have received 3 sms in the numbers from 0-9, 2 in those of 10-99 and 1 in those of 100-999, but it begins to fail in those of order 1000.

This is the part of the script that send the sms

```
class TextMessage:

def setNumero(self, numero):
    self.numero = numero

def setContenido(self, contenido):
    self.contenido = contenido

def setPuerto(self, puerto):
    self.puerto = puerto

def conectar(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial(self.puerto, 460800, timeout=5)
    time.sleep(1)
def configurar(self):
    self.ser.write(b'AT\r')
    #time.sleep(1)
    # s = self.ser.read(15)
    # print(s.decode())

    self.ser.write(b'ATZ\r')
    #time.sleep(1)
    # s = self.ser.read(15)
    # print(s.decode())

    self.ser.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    # s = self.ser.read(15)
    # print(s.decode())

def enviarMensaje(self):
    self.ser.write(b'AT+CMGS="')
    self.ser.write(self.numero.encode())
    self.ser.write(b'"\r')
    self.ser.write(self.contenido.encode())
    self.ser.write(b'\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ser.write(b'\x1A')
    #time.sleep(1)
    s = self.ser.read(10)
    print(s.decode())

def desconectar(self):
    self.ser.close()
```

#

```
def EnviarSMS():
    archivo = ruta + "numeros.txt"
    #contadorSMS.set('0')
    with open(archivo) as f:
        numero = f.readline()
        cnt = 1
        sms = TextMessage()
        sms.setPuerto(puertoAsignado(puerto.get()))
        sms.setContenido(mensaje.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
        sms.conectar()
        sms.configurar()
        while numero:
            sms.setNumero(numero)
            sms.enviarMensaje()
            #contadorSMS.set(str(cnt))
            numero = f.readline()
            cnt += 1
    mensajeEmergente = 'Los SMS fueron enviados'
    mensajeVar = tk.Message(ventana, width=140, text=mensajeEmergente)
    mensajeVar.config(bg='lightgreen')
    mensajeVar.grid(row=2, column=3)
    sms.desconectar()
```

Thanks to all community

Comment: _"In theory it should have received 3 sms in the numbers from 0-9, 2 in those of 10-99 and 1 in those of 100-999, but it begins to fail in those of order 1000."_ - Help me to understand: does it mean that you receive 0 SMSs in the range 100-999, only 1 in the range 10-99 and only two in the range 0-9? How can you be sure that those messages are not received? Do you possess 1000 different SIMs with contiguous phone numbers?

Comment: No,but i have 3 of those numbers and sometimes the sms didn´t arrive

Comment: Forgive the question: are you sure that there's room in SMS memoories of the receivers?

Comment: I mean: `+CMGS: <N>` means that the SMS has correctly been delivered to the network. If they are not delivered to the recipients in a _reasonable_ amount of time (an SMS could take tens of minutes to be delivered in case of congested network) it means the problem resides in receivers.

Comment: (Another possible reason, but I actually never heard about it, could be the network chosing to not deliver messages for some reason. Maybe identifies you as a spammer?)

Comment: Well, it´s something weird, if the transmission speed is low everything works but if I increase the speed to save every few seconds for each sms it is when they stop arriving, I don't know what the reason is, it is as if the modem did not manage to dispatch the sms, I don't know if it I can make some configuration for this to change.

Comment: I would place my bet on the network operator, instead.